# I am new in react, i had installed react route dom and then get this error

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar'
import Index from './components/layout/Index';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
              <React exact path="/" component={Index} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am getting error like this------------

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
>   components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
>   object.

Check the render method of `App`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Inside the switch it should be `Route` not `React`;

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar'
import Index from './components/layout/Index';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```